# How to get aws_cdk version in python

Tags: python, aws-cdk

is there any possibility to receive the aws_cdk version within python.
I do not want do call `cdk --version`, I want to get the version natively like

```py
import aws_cdk
print(aws_cdk.__version__)
```

But I receive `AttributeError: module 'aws_cdk' has no attribute '__version__'`.

I am using aws_cdk in version 1.62 and there is no attribute for `security_groups` within the `aws_ecs_patterns.ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService` construct.

And upgrading is not a solution for me right now.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with this library, and I think this is not proper way, but I hope it helps you until someone offers better option

```
import subprocess
x = subprocess.check_output('pip3 show aws_cdk.aws-s3')
lines = x.split(b"\n")
for line in lines:
    if line.find(b"Version") != -1:
        print(line)
        break
```